# get String value not as hex from smartcontract

Tags: solidity, web3js

I got a smartcontract function returning several values on of them as string

I've trying to transform this number to UTF with web3 and is not working.
If I try it on remix calling the smart contract it's works fine... but not from JS

my current code in the smart contract are

```
    function getToken(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (
        string _tokenName,
        string _cryptoCardID,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _nextPrice,
        address _owner
    ) {
        _tokenName = doggies[_tokenId].name;
        _cryptoCardID = doggies[_tokenId].cryptoCardID;
        _price = tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId];
        _nextPrice = nextPriceOf(_tokenId);
        _owner = tokenIdToOwner[_tokenId];
    }

from JS


 for ( var i = 0; i < result; i++){

  myfunction.getToken.call(  i ,  function (error, resultGetAll) {
  console.log("Token ID:"+i+ "Data:"+JSON.stringify(resultGetAll)); //here i get _cryptoCardID as hex 0x000000...
                                    
                                    
   }) // each one
                           
}// for
```

what I expected is a string in readable form (utf8)

Answer (score 1):

Contracts will store the binary data, so returning the data in hexadecimal form is a more efficient way of viewing this data.

You can always decode the hex to utf-8 with a utility function from the web3 library.

**Note:** this method may differ depending on your web3 version, see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/2.x/packages/web3-utils/src/Utils.js#L243) for `web3.utils.hexToUtf8` alternative.

Example:

```
$ web3.toUtf8("0x68656c6c6f20776f726c640000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
$ "hello world"
```

*tested on web3 version:* `0.20.3`